# I'm trying to use `.filter` to only return the string elements from an array, but I'm not too sure how to do it

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve a series of problems and one of these problems requires me to write a function which returns all the string elements in multiple arrays. However, I am not too sure how to go about using filter properly.

This is my attempt to solve the problem.

```
function stringsOnly(array) {

  array.filter(function(array) {
    return (typeof array === 'string') && !!array

  })
}
```

These are the arrays I am trying to filter through and return only the strings('').

```
describe('stringsOnly', () => {
  it('should return only the strings of an array', () => {

    expect(stringsOnly([10, 'Mike', '23', NaN, 'elephant'])).to.deep.equal(['Mike', '23', 'elephant'])

    expect(stringsOnly([{}, [], 99, false])).to.deep.equal([])

    expect(stringsOnly(['I', 'am', 'the', 'eggman'])).to.deep.equal(['I', 'am', 'the', 'eggman'])

  })
})
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your output from that?

Comment: @TylerRoper maybe some, but if a little checkmark is stopping you from helping people, you're in the wrong game.

Comment: @SterlingArcher I agree, and it's not about reputation. It's about making sure that questions are accurately marked as answered instead of lying dormant and cluttering the repository. If unaccepted answers were a deterrent then I wouldn't have as many as I do :P

Comment: did you try console.logging your return value to see what was going on? it seems that it would quickly become apparent that youre not testing the desired element.

Comment: Thank you all so much for taking the time to stop by and trying to help me, it turns out that I was only missing the word "return" on the second line haha.

Comment: Also, @TylerRoper I hear you. I didn't mean to be rude, I'm just pretty new to all this and I'm a bit unattentive at times...

Comment: @MortalSumo No worries. As a newer user I was just trying to point you in the right direction. Here's a related article: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not returning the result of the filter method in your stringOnly function.

```
function stringsOnly(array) {
  return array.filter(function(elem) {  // notice the return at the beginning of this line
    return (typeof elem === 'string') 
  })
}
```

Comment: Oh wow... Thank you so much for this, I only needed to add that return on the second line and it passed. I feel silly now haha.